# fill_between with discrete x-values and where parameter produces gaps

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an area plot where the fill changes based on the y value. Using `fill_between` and the `where` parameter mostly works, but leaves unfilled areas:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(1,10)
y=np.array([1,4,6,8,4,7,5,6,0])

plt.plot(x, y, color='black')
plt.fill_between(x, y, where=y < 5, color='red')
plt.fill_between(x, y, where=y >= 5, color='blue')

plt.show()
```

[Run on trinket.io](https://trinket.io/python3/95c4e3ff06)

Produces this result: [Plot without interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVt49.png)

What does it take to get rid of any white areas below the graph? I don't have strict requirements as to how the current "in-between" areas ought to be coloured. Either - or both, meeting at a mid-point - will do.

Adding `interpolate=True` improves the situation slightly in some ways, but in other ways it looks more messy: [Plot with interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8JUB.png)

I've looked at the `step` parameter, but that doesn't seem promising to my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirements are simple, the best way is to probably decide your "default" colour and use that as the fill_between for the entire curve without specifying any condition. On top of this, you can add different colors for different conditions. Something like:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.fill_between(x, y, color="blue")
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y<=5, color="red")
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]